# OSX - Convert GLSL 'InOut' to Metal

Tags: macos, glsl, metalanguage

I am trying to convert the `GLSL` function below:

```
float pMod1(inout float p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return c;
}
```

to use in `Metal`

```
static float pMod1( thread float &p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return c;
}
```

Then use it:

```
static float map( float3 p )
{
    p.x = pMod1(p.x,10);
    ...
}
```

and I got an error:

> Non-cont reference cannot bind to vector element

1. How to resolve this issue?
2. What is the equivalent qualifier for `InOut` in `Metal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

first you have to define it:

```
#define _inout(T) T
```

Then use it in your function:

```
static float somefunction( _inout(float) p)
```